# Setting BASH as the default in SCO

Tags: bash, sco

I have tried countless times, trying to get `bash` as the default shell in SCO, and have failed.

I have tried the following:

1. **Installed Bash** - using `bash-2.05a.pkg`
2. **Installed Readline** - using `readline-4.2a.pkg`

I installed them by using:

```
pkgadd -d - < bash-2.05a.pkg
pkgadd -d - < readline-4.2a.pkg
```

I then added bash to my `.profile`. This is the contents:

```
stty intr '^C'

#SHELL=/bin/sh
SHELL=/usr/local/bin/bash
HOME=/
PATH=/bin:/etc:/usr/bin:/tcb/bin:/usr/local/bin

# set terminal type
#eval `tset -m scoansi:${TERM:-scoansi} -m :\?${TERM:-scoansi} -e -r -s -Q`
TERM=bash
export TERM PATH SHELL HOME

[ -x /bin/mesg ] && mesg n              # if mesg is installed...

if [ -f $HOME/.kshrc -a -r $HOME/.kshrc ]; then
    # ksh88: intent is that $ENV is set only for interactive shells,
    # ksh93 easier since it doesn't source $ENV when run non-interactively.
    # $_ is set to 1.  $_flags (shell flags, e.g. ismh) is set to 0
    # Then one of the two is subtracted from their sum:
    # either $_, if ${-%%*i*} evaluates to null (will for an interactive shell),
    # or $_flags (for a non-interactive shell - i not set ).
    # ENV will only be set if the result is 0, since only ENVFILE[0] is set.
    ENV='${_ENVFILE[(_=1)+(_$-=0)-_${-%%*i*}]}'
    _ENVFILE=/.kshrc
    export ENV _ENVFILE
fi
```

I had a look online, and people have suggested I do this:

```
# cat /etc/shells
#       @(#) shells 95.1 00/10/29
#
/bin/csh
/bin/sh
/bin/ksh
/usr/bin/scosh
/bin/bash
/usr/bin/bash

# exec /bin/bash
/bin/bash: not found
```

I have even tried searching the machine for all to do with `bash`, like this:

```
#find / -name bash*
/usr/local/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/bashbug
/usr/local/info/bash.info
/usr/local/man/man1/bash.1
/usr/local/man/man1/bashbug.1
/usr/options/bash.name
/opt/K/SCO/lynx/5.0.7a/usr/lib/lynx/lynx_help/keystrokes/bashlike_edit_help.html
/opt/bash-2.05a.pkg
/var/adm/pkg/bash
```

(**Note:** No bash.rc there)

```
#find / -name .bash*
# (nothing)
```

**So how do I set `bash` as the default shell in SCO?**

Comment: Doesn't SCO specify a user's shell in `/etc/passwd`? Also you obivously need to run `/usr/local/bin/bash` to start a bash ...

Comment: @Bananguin How do you mean run that? If I just run that as is, I get an error back: `dynamic linker : /usr/local/bin/bash : could not open /usr/lib/libthread.so.1
Killed`

Comment: Does that file exist on your system?

Comment: `/etc/passwd` does, and I can see the user that I have, and their entry in that file: `test:x:200:50::/u/test:/bin/sh`. I went to the: `/usr/local/bin/` and it shows `bash` and `bahsbug` there.

Comment: I meant `/usr/lib/libthread.so.1`. Apparently bash needs that library but it can't be loaded.

Comment: Nah, that is not found. How can I install / recover it?

Comment: I'm sure there is a containing package for it which you can search for ...

Comment: I couldn't find an appropriate package online, so I am installing the Maintenance Pack 5 and also verified the system - lets see if that fixes the issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found out, that I needed to verify the System and the Software, using `scoadmin`. Then once that was done, I installed SCO Maintenance Pack 5, and rebooted the machine.

Now when I type:

```
# bash
bash-3.1#
```

Getting bash on the machine works great!

**Edit**
This also works with the standard user too (not just the root user).